# Possibility of Streaming Upload in Spring Boot 3.x.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload, apache-commons

I am trying to upgrade my Spring Boot Project to 3 from 2.7.x, however one issue hindering my attempt is the removal of support for the Apache Commons Multipart file upload functionality, in favour of the built-in **StandardServletMultipartResolver**.

This presents an issue currently, as the API makes use of streaming uploads to deal with large files without causing too many issues with excessive memory usage.

Does anyone have a workaround for this, an alternative solution, or some experience working with large files in Spring Boot 3? Thanks.